# Get the max balance for specific user SQL server

Tags: sql-server, max

I have a specific query where I need to get the Max Balance for a specific user. 
With this query I am able to get the Max ID value  (max row value) and get corresponding user and balance.
How can I get this to work for a specific User only, example User 1010102 ?
Basically getting balance for max transaction (ID) of a specific ACCOUNT_ID?
I tried to insert a `where ACCOUNT_ID = 1010102` in the last select with no luch

```
SELECT 
ID,
ACCOUNT_ID,
BALANCE_RAW_LOYALTY
FROM ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL)
```

Comment: Please give some sample data and expected results.. its much clearer than trying to explain in words.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `condition` inside your `subquery`, not in the main query.

```
select
ID,
ACCOUNT_ID,
BALANCE_RAW_LOYALTY
FROM ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL
WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = 1010102)
```

**or** you do this without using a `subquery`.

```
select TOP 1
ID,
ACCOUNT_ID,
BALANCE_RAW_LOYALTY
FROM ACCOUNT_TRAN_ALL
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = 1010102
ORDER BY ID DESC
```